# Disable Firefox auto-update in Linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, auto-update, xvfb, selenium-firefoxdriver

In my current project, I require Firefox browser to be run in headless mode using Xvfb and Selenium. In order to maintain compatibility between Selenium and Firefox, I want to maintain both of them at a specific version and stop Firefox auto-upgrades.

Currently, I am installing Firefox by the following steps:

1. Downloading a specific version of Firefox (wget http://kickstart/redhat/enterprise/fupdates/5.4C/x86_64/firefox-31.6.0-2.0.el5amzn.x86_64.rpm).
2. Installing the downloaded version (rpm -i firefox-31.6.0-2.0.el5amzn.x86_64.rpm).

"app.update.auto", "app.update.enabled" and "app.update.silent" [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZApP.png) parameters (in "about:config") of the Firefox profile are disabled by default.
Does that mean it would not be auto-updated? Is it the case with such types of installation?

Any recommendation would be helpful.

Comment: Are the configuration changes done using browser? or modified using files? Did you happen to check [this](http://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-automatic-updates-in-firefox)?

Comment: @Rao, the configuration was present by default. After following steps 1 and 2, I just checked the configuration settings from the browser and it was already disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can set these prefs in `about:config` to disable automatic updating:

```
app.update.auto - false
app.update.enabled - false
app.update.silent - false
```

You need to enter about:config in the address bar and then search for each pref in a list.

Comment: Thanks @4M01. But, these configuration settings are set to false by default in the "about:config" of the installed Firefox. Just wanted to understand why these are set to false by default. Is it anything to do with the way of installation (steps 1 and 2 above).

Comment: @Avipsa, I am not sure why it's showing disabled by default. Any standard installation always has auto update by default ON. This is to make sure user uses very recent app which is less vulnerable and more enhanced, secured.

Comment: @Avipsa, Just curious why don't you use https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Answer (score 1):

In linux, one solution is that after you download firefox and extract it ([you can download tar from here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)).
Then change the owner and group to root, for example:

```
find .|xargs sudo chown root
find .|xargs sudo chgrp root
```

Because of the permission, firefox cannot update now

Answer (score 0):

When installing Firefox, choose the customize radio button instead of default installation may be in 2nd or 3rd screen of the installation wizard and `uncheck`  Mozilla/Firefox `maintenance service`. It will certainly work.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 files under the installation directory (at least on windows. So I believe, similar files should be on linux as well).

```
1. updater.exe
2. updater.ini
3. update-settings.init
```

After removing these files, I was able to stop auto upgrade. Deleting these files will automatically change the auto update of firefox i.e. settings>advanced>Never check for update option as well.

**Important: Remove these files before your first launch of the browser.**

Hope this helps someone. :)